# Symfony All blank pages after cache clear

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I recently was making changes to my Symfony 2 site and then did a clear cache command on the site. Afterwards when I returned to the site the pages were blank.

Here's the command I ran

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I've heard that it might be related to file permissions on the cache folder, but I'm not sure.
I logged in at the root level to be able to run the run the above command becuase I was getting an 'access denied' error when i was logged in at the user level.

Any helped/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please check your webserver log-files and symfony's production log in app/logs/prod.log for errors.

Comment: nothing in the server log files, and the prod log file was complaining about permission being denied to the app/cache/annotations folder, but that was before I ran the cache:clear with the web user.

Comment: What OS are you using? I had an issue on Windows when there was some kind of weird race condition regarding how the cache was build up. It couldn't move `dev_new` to the just deleted `dev` folder.

I extended the cache console command and added a 1s sleep which magically fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have run `cache:clear` as root user without the `--no-warmup` flag.

Now symfony has warmed the cache after clearing it using the root account which would result in the newly created cache files being owned by your root user. Depending on your `umask` the webserver-user now might not have r+w access to these files.

Make sure your webserver-user / cgi-user has read and write access to your cache folder or give the ownership back to this user.

```
sudo chown webserver_user:webserver_group -R app/cache
sudo chmod 770 -R app/cache  # or use acl to permit read/write to your webserver-user
```

Comment: I went back in as the root user and reran the cache:clear WITH the --no-warmup flag. Then I logged in as the webserver user and ran cache:clear without --no-warmup again so the new cache files would be created & belong to the webserver user. I then ran chmod 770 and can confirm that the cache folder and its siblings are all set with rwxrwx--- ... but still just a blank screen. Anything else I can change?

Comment: I've managed to fix the problem. Since you were headed in the right direction, I'm marking this as the correct answer. I did need to 'chown' on the cache directory to get it to work, but I was changing to the wrong webserver_user. Here is what I used.
    chown apache:psacln -R app/cache

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the permissions for the `app/cache` and `app/logs` are set correctly for **both the web server user and the CLI user**. 
[The Symfony Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) has instructions on how to do it.

If your OS supports`chmod +a` (OSX) you can do the following:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*
$ sudo chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

If your OS supports `setfacl` (Ubuntu, for example) and ACL support is enabled, you can do the following:

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Note: both examples assume that the username for the web server user is `www-data`

Comment: he does neither need to remove the cache nor the completly unrelated logs folder to resolve the issue ... acl has to be enabled in order to use it ( which it aint i.e. in a Debian minimal install by default ) ... but if acl is available it's a good way to fine-tune permissions ... **but** please note that the cache folder content created during cache warmup after running `cache:clear` is now owned by root which is (usually) not desired and is being fixed by chown as pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Second option works for me after an "apt-get install acl" ! Thank you